# mySQL Query to find where two rows time does not meet criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I was looking for a little help. I have a SQL database of incidents that happen. Each incident has actions and a date of the action.

```
Incident_id   Action_id     Date
0001          76            11/1/2016 13:12:000
0001          18            11/1/2016 22:45:342
0002          76            11/2/2016 13:11:000
0002          18            11/1/2016 22:14:342
0003          76            11/1/2016 13:08:000
0003          18            11/3/2016 22:15:342
```

What I need to know is, after action_id 76 occurs, when action_id 18 does not happen within 24 hours on the same incident_id. Using this criteria, the query would return incident_id 0003 from the simple database above.

I can write a query that tells me when action_id 18 happens after action_id 76, but that is not enough. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Matt

Answer (score 0):

`NOT EXISTS` comes to mind:

```
select i.*
from incidents i
where i.action_id = 76 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from incidents i2
                  where i2.incident_id = i.incident_id and
                        i2.action_id = 18 and
                        i2.date >= i.date and
                        i2.date < date_add(i.date, interval 1 day)
                 );
```

Comment: @Mattrajotte . . . The syntax looks good to me.  Are you sure you are using MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

I think this one will do the job
Edit: corrected the table_name and date field name in query

```
 SELECT * FROM incidents WHERE DATE > DATE_SUB(Date,INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND action_id=76
```

Comment: I have updated the answer, try debugging query. there must be an error in table_name or something @Mattrajotte

Comment: This doesn't work. Maybe the server is not MySQL... also, 18 and 76 are not the only action_ids, so I believe this would return any action_id.